# undefined is not being discarded through typeof check

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Can someone explain why this doesn't work?

```
let o: { a?: number; b?: string } = {}
let a: ['a', 'b'] = ['a', 'b']

a.forEach((v) => {
  if (typeof o[v] !== "undefined") {
    let a = o[v] // type string | number | undefined
  }
})
```

i was hoping to get only string | number, any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 1):

Assign `o[v]` to a variable. Technically, `o[v]` *could* point to a different value within the `if` statement than the inner block: `v` could change; `o[v]` could be a property getter; or something else could happen so that `o[v]` produces a different value after a subsequent call.

Assigning to a variable tells TS that it's the **same value** being checked.

```
a.forEach((v) => {
  const value = o[v]; 
  if (typeof value !== "undefined") {
    let a = value // type string | number
  }
})
```

#### Note on Changes to this Answer

Previously, the question included `typeof o[v] === undefined` as the condition. This has been corrected to read `typeof o[v] === "undefined"`.

As I noted in my original answer, `typeof` expressions return a string, so `tyepof o[v] !== undefined` will always return true.

Comment: i haven't heard of this technique before thank u! saved me hours of research

Comment: Glad I could help. Remember, you should [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to let others know your problem has been solved.